# 3D in Fedora - are there any mesa like packages?

Tags: linux, fedora-14

When i was using Debian on my PC, i just:

apt-get install -y mesa-utils libgl1-mesa-dri

and then...the 3D games, like torcs didn't lag anymore.

Question: Are there any "mesa" -""like"" packages in Fedora, that i can install, so that e.g.: torcs will not lag after installing it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This howto from the Fedora forums may help - it details how to install ATI drivers:

http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=155503

There's some background info here too:

http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?p=1417654

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
i don't have an ATI vga, intel x3100, but for some reason it's named like: GM965/GL960?